# How to add a an amount to variable after progress bar is loaded and display the amount

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i have a little problem, im a newbie in coding so i am trying to learn...
I have a button that launches a progress bar but i would like it so when the progress bar is done it adds $1 to my money variable. heres my code:
Global variable declaring code:

```
<script> var money; money = 0; </script>
```

Proggress bar script:

```
<script>
function move() {
var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
var width = 0;
var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);

    } else {

        width++; 
        elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
        document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
}
}
</script>
```

My money varable script:
    
        var money
        money = 0
    
My money peice that is supposed to show up:

```
<b class="text">
<img src="http://www.diamondhunt.co/images/pic_coin.png" alt="Smiley face" align="middle">
```

MONEY: $

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(money);
</script>
```

Ive tried diong this:

```
<script>
function move() {
var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
var width = 0;
var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
        money = money + 1;
    } else {

        width++; 
        elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
        document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
}
```

}

i tried lots of things, i searched online adn asked frinds help i hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable money is defined in the function frame(), so every time you call this function - it is a new variable.

You need to declare smth like this

```
var money = 0;
```

before the function (above the function).

Read more about this [Javascript Scope](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Comment: oh sorry i forgot a snippet of code: <script> var money; money = 0; </script>

Comment: But then if i call the variable above the function, then how do i add 1 dollar or just 1 to it when the proggress bar is done?